# how to force linking on linux libgpod and rhythmbox

Tags: linux, linker, ubuntu-10.10, rhythmbox

Ok, I've added some functionality to a linux library.

However even after 'make install' the program I'm trying to confirm functionality is linking to the previous version.

So 'make install' puts my libraries here:
'/usr/local/lib'
and
'/usr/local/include'

I used the following on configure:
./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-uninstalled-build 'CFLAGS=-g -O0' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O0' 'JFLAGS=-g -O0' 'FFLAGS=-g -O0' CPPFLAGS='-L /usr/local/lib/ -I /usr/local/include/gpod-1.0/'

But when I try to execute the program I get 'Symbol not found' and 'Plugin can not load'

When I ldd the produced plugin so:
~/Development/rhythmbox/plugins/ipod/.libs$ ldd libipod.so

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00d97000)

librhythmbox-core.so.1 => /home/gary/Development/rhythmbox/shell/.libs/librhythmbox core.so.1 (0x009ad000)

**libgpod.so.4 => /usr/lib/libgpod.so.4 (0x00509000)**

The emphasis being stressed because it's obviously linking to the wrong library...  When I look in the make file I see the following:

IPOD_CFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/local/include/gpod-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12

IPOD_LIBS = -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lgpod -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lpng12 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0

So the CPPFLAGS are being passed through to the plugin, and in .deps I see the proper header file being included... IE:

~/Development/rhythmbox/plugins/ipod/.deps$ less rb-ipod-source.Po | grep gpod

/usr/local/include/gpod-1.0/gpod/itdb.h ../../lib/eel-gconf-extensions.h

/usr/local/include/gpod-1.0/gpod/itdb.h:

Ubuntu 10.10

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `libgpod.so.4` installed to `/usr/local/lib`?  If it is, contents of `$LD_RUN_PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `/etc/ld.so.conf`?

Comment: ld.so.conf=include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf  Other 2 variables are empty...  libgpod.so.4 does exist on /usr/local/lib  It looks like it's finding the old version...

Comment: In the meantime until this has been figured out I've changed my install directory on the library to overwrite the production version...  Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `LD_RUN_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib` before running `configure` and `make`.  This will embed `/usr/local/lib` as a shared library search path into the executable.

Comment: I haven't confirmed this as of yet, however several people have confirmed it as being correct now.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`libgpod.so` is pointing to the old version of the library.